Error "parseResult on ToolCallingAgentOutputParser only works on ChatGeneration output" with Ollama Model and Custom Tool
I'm working with Langchain.js v2 and trying to use the Ollama LLM to build a custom tool and agent using the createToolCallingAgent. However, I am encountering the following error:
Error: parseResult on ToolCallingAgentOutputParser only works on ChatGeneration output

I've tried to follow the documentation and create a simple custom tool that adds 2 to the input number. My full code is below:
import { tool } from "@langchain/core/tools";
import { z } from "zod";
import { Ollama } from "@langchain/ollama";
import { ChatPromptTemplate,  MessagesPlaceholder } from "@langchain/core/prompts";
import { createToolCallingAgent } from "langchain/agents";
import { AgentExecutor } from "langchain/agents";

const llm = new Ollama({
    model: "llama3",
    temperature: 0.7,
});

const magicTool = tool(
    async (input) => {
        return `${ input + 2}`;
    },
    {
        name: "magic_function",
        description: "Applies a magic function to an input",
        schema: z.object({
            input: z.number(),
        })
    }
);

const tools = [magicTool];

// Prompt Template
const prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
    ["system", "You are a helpful assistant called iHelp"],
    ["placeholder", "{chat_history}"],
    ["human", "{input}"],
    ["placeholder", "{agent_scratchpad}"],
]);

const agent = createToolCallingAgent({
    llm,
    tools,
    prompt,
});

const agentExecutor = new AgentExecutor({
    agent,
    tools,
});

const query = "What is the value of magic_function(3)?";

await agentExecutor.invoke({ input: query });

